# Lodash sumBy return null when all values are null

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to use `_.sumBy` to return `null` when all values are `null`.

Given this array:

```
[
   {
      "productId":10001,
      "name":"abc",
      "orderSize":null
   },
   {
      "productId":10002,
      "name":"def",
      "orderSize":null
   }
]
```

I want the return to be `null`.

Given this array:

```
[
   {
      "productId":10001,
      "name":"abc",
      "orderSize":5
   },
   {
      "productId":10002,
      "name":"def",
      "orderSize":15
   }
]
```

I want the return to be 20.

I'm trying to do this with:

```
_.sumBy(myArray, x => x['orderSize'] ?? null)
```

This works fine for the second case but when both values are `null`,  it's returning `0` instead of `null`.

EDIT:

The reason I ask is because when the array has only one element then it does return `null`.

```
_.sumBy([{
      "productId":10001,
      "name":"abc",
      "orderSize":null
   }], x => x['orderSize'] ?? null)
```

Comment: Why should that be possible? According to the documentation, `sumBy` returns a number. If you want anything different, you need to code it on your own

Comment: `_.sumBy() || null`

Comment: See https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4110 for the bug report where this has been introduced

Comment: I've added an update explaining why I thought it might be possible.

Comment: Yeah, even the bug report talks about that special and unexpected result. If you want it fixed, open a bug report